# Characteristic value or eigenvalues and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am having semester in linear algebra. And have recently got acquainted to eigenvalues.

What is the relation between eigenvalues and determinant? Going through answers of some questions I found suggestion of using eigenvalues to determine determinant of matrix. I just know $\det(eI-A)=0$ where e is eigenvalue of A. How to use this fact to calculate determinant of A?

Comment: I am sure you are aware that to make sure that you have *all* the eigenvalues, you need the underlying field to be algebraically closed. For instance, the real matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ has the complex eigenvalues $i, -i$. And then, over such an algebraically closed field one can prove that by choosing a suitable basis (that is, suitably conjugating) a matrix can be put in triangular form. Then it is clear that the eigenvalues are the element on the diagonal (just compute the characteristic polynomial), and that their product is the determinant.

Answer (score 2):

You know that the eigenvalues are the roots (zeros) of the characteristic polynomial, i.e. of the polynomial $(x) = \det(xI - A)$. Watch what happens of you evaluate that polynomial at $0$, i.e. compute $p(0)$. You get $p(0) = \det(0I-A) = \det(-A)$. Now, $\det(-A) = (-1)^n\det A$ (assuming that A is a $n\times n$ matrix).

So how do you find $p(0)$, if you only have the eigenvalues of $A$. Well, since the eigenvalues of $A$ are the zeros of $p(x)$, you can write $p(x)$ as a product $$
  p(x) = \alpha(x - \lambda_1)(x - \lambda_2)\ldots(x - \lambda_n)
$$
where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the zeros of $p(x)$, i.e. the eigenvalues of $A$. Note that some particular $\lambda$ will appear more than once in this list, if $p(x)$ has a zero with an order higher than 1 at $\lambda$. For characteristic polynomials, you also know that $\alpha = 1$, because the coefficient of $x^n$ in the characteristic polynomial of a $n\times n$ matrix is always $1$. Now watch what happens if you evaluate $p$ at $0$. You get $$
  p(0) = (0 - \lambda_1)(0 - \lambda_2)\ldots(0 - \lambda_n) = (-1)^n\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n \text{.}
$$

Combining these results, you have $$
  p(0) = (-1)^n\det A = (-1)^n\lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n
  \implies
  \det A = \lambda_1\ldots\lambda_n \text{.}
$$

Comment: @user76797 Did you downvote? If so, you might want to care to explain why...

Answer (score 0):

if you have polynomial $\det (A-xI)$  you put $x=0$then you can catch $\det(A)$ obviously.

if you have only eigen value you must be careful if sum of number of eigen values (or more exact sum of dim eigen vector spaces) be equal dim A then you can find polynomial $\det (A-xI)$ with it's root (eigen values) and so again you will have  $\det A$ again. $$(\lambda_1-x)*....*(\lambda_n-x)$$

Answer (score -2):

Write the characteristic polynomial $\chi_A$ as $\chi_A(X)=\prod_{\lambda\text{ eigenvalue}}(X-\lambda)$; what is $\chi_A(0)$? You can express it as the constant coefficient (easy to compute, function of the eigenvalues only), or with your expression above (taking your "$e$" to be 0))

(in the product, the $\lambda$'s are not necessarily distinct)

Comment: $det(A) = \lambda_1^{m_1} \cdot \lambda_2^{m_2} \cdots \lambda_l^{m_l}$ where $m_i$ is the multiplicity of the corresponding eigenvalue, can I can an explanation?

Comment: @ClementC. This only works if you know that the characteristic polynomial is monic (i.e., the coefficient of its largest power is 1). Otherwise, the zeros do *not* uniquely define the polynomial. Now, the characteristic polynomial always *is* monic, so your answer is correct, but I'm not sure the OP knows that...

Comment: @user76797: what explanation do you want? (what you wrote is indeed the case, it is a valid expression for the determinant)
fgp: I assumed it was known, indeed.

Comment: @ClementC.:How it is true, and is it true in all cases?

Comment: @user76797: if you accept the fact that the expression for $\chi_A$ is the right one (it has the right roots, for a start [*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial), then you can prove it as explained above.

Otherwise, you can also (if you have already seen this) use triangularisability (in $\mathbb{C}$) for matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.